# Set selectedIndex within a select

Tags: jquery, select

I want to change the selectedIndex of an select element. As you can see below the selectedIndex is marked when I click on the dropdown field. But why it isn't changed on top of select? In the example it still have name of the first option (Test1) .

EDIT: I'm using JQuery Mobile.

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="ui-field-contain">
                               <select name="select-native-3"id="selectRule"
                            data-iconpos="left">
                            <option value="0">Test 1</option>
                            <option value="1">Test 2</option>
                            <option value="2">Test 3></option>     
                        </select> </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$( window ).load(function() {

$('#selectRule').get(0).selectedIndex = 2;

}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Just wondering, are you using a plugin or what? Because otherwise your code would work

Comment: @Wolff, no im not using any plugin.

Comment: Ahh, I have to mention that im using JQuery Mobile.

Comment: So ya, you are using a plugin.... :) You have to trigger `change()` event. The easiest way is: `$('#selectRule').val(2).change();`. EDIT: i'm not a jq mobile user but apparently the correct way would be: `$('#selectRule').val(2).selectmenu("refresh", true);`

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
$(function() {
    $("#selectRule").val(2);
});
```

Comment: Still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        function JXX_SelectOption(Index)
        {
            $('#selectRule option:eq(' + Index + ')').attr("selected", "selected");
        }
        JXX_SelectOption(1);

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ui-field-contain">
                               <select name="select-native-3"id="selectRule"
                            data-iconpos="left">
                            <option value="0">Test 1</option>
                            <option value="1">Test 2</option>
                            <option value="2">Test 3</option>     
                        </select> </div>

</body>
</html>
```